# Serialization of Generic Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, collections

I have a class named "City"

```
public class City
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public int StateID {get; set;}
   public int CountryID{get; set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   .......

}
```

and i have an asp.net page named CityAdd.aspx, in this page i want to create a collection of city class that can be store in the viewstate. 
Is it possible to make a Generic Collection Serializable?

Comment: have you try to store collection of City class in view state? any exceptions?

Comment: Most common .NET Framework collection types can be serialized by default

Comment: Type 'Project.City' in Assembly 'Classes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do as below, add Serializable attribute

```
[Serializable] 
public class City
{
}
```